# Swift for loop nested array performance

Tags: ios, swift, syntax

**Which is better performance?**

**Option 1**

```
var sections: [SubMenu]

var selectedItem: BeverageItem? {
    var item: BeverageItem?
    for section in sections {
        for beverage in section.beverages {
            if beverage.isSelected {
                item = beverage
                break
            }
        }
    }
    return item
}
```

**Option 2**

```
var selectedItem: BeverageItem? {
    var item: BeverageItem?
    if let subMenuIndex = sections.index(where: { (subMenu) -> Bool in
        for beverage in subMenu.beverages {
            if beverage.isSelected {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }) {
        let subMenu = sections[subMenuIndex]
        if let beverageIndex = subMenu.beverages.index(where: { (beverage) -> Bool in
            return beverage.isSelected
        }) {
            item = subMenu.beverages[beverageIndex]
        }
    }
    return item
}
```

If option 1 then where would you use option 2 and why?

Comment: How large are your arrays? Unless they are very large, the difference is probably negligible and you should use what you understand better. – For large arrays, use Instruments, profile and compare.

Comment: When it comes to performance questions, the answer always is: what did you measure?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

For unsorted arrays here most simple efficient way (result equal to your first solution):

```
var sections: [SubMenu]

var selectedItem: BeverageItem? {
    for section in sections.reverse() {// remove .reverse() if you don't really need last existed section
        for beverage in section.beverages {
            if beverage.isSelected {
                return beverage
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```